# How to find out on Windows what ssthresh and cwnd it has computed for the connection

Tags: windows, tcp

I would like to find out what ssthresh and cwnd has Windows computed for the connection.

For example on Linux I can do

```
ip route show cache
```

to see the computed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in Windows, but you have to program it yourself.  Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The  GetPerTcpConnectionEStats function (available since Vista) can get you all kinds of info, like cwnd, ssthresh, dupack's, rtt's, sack's and much more about TCPv4 connections. Use GetPerTcp6ConnectionEStats for TCPv6.

**Edit**: The SDK has a utility that can show you this information.  Here it is in c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\tcpanalyzer.exe.  I think it's the Platform SDK from Microsoft ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279 ).